# Encountered an error while running a file through GDB

Tags: windows-7, gdb

I'm trying to run a file using GDB but it shows me the following error:

Error creating process C:\Users\Admin\desktop\inctfj\tired, (error 193).

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of your code? you might get better help when people can see what you have tried to do

Comment: Well, I didn't made the program, I downloaded it to practice Reverse Engineering. All I did was I added some breakpoints and tried to run it.

Comment: Do you expect people to guess what is written in this program you downloaded? I believe it would be unlikely that you get help with your question in its current state

Comment: Error 193 is [ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT), so is this really a windows application?